# Cassandra token range distribution with vnodes

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

My cassandra cluster is setup with vnodes (num_tokens=32).

I want to know if the token range distribution across various nodes will change over time. The reason I am asking is we are planning to use tablesnap to backup the data - for disaster recovery. In the eventuality of needing to restore a new cluster, we need to restore using the token range method.

I am planning to take a backup of nodetool ring command for each of the nodes in S3 and then use it to restore in the new cluster. Would like to know if the token range distribution changes overtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes it could do if you add or remove nodes. The simplest way to test it is by setting up a 3 node cluster, checking `nodetool ring`, then adding a 4th and then rechecking.

You're probably better off restoring data into the cluster using something like `sstableloader`

Comment: So as long as I don't expand the cluster, the token ring distribution does not change? If yes, then I can choose to take a copy of token rings every time the cluster is expanded.

Comment: sstableloader takes a lot of time. For ex: in our case, it runs for 20 hours for the data size we have. In DR, we would like to keep the downtime as minimal as possible.

Comment: the tokens are assigned when the node is initialized. it doesn't change after that unless, as markc mentioned, you add a node.